# Vuejs model inserting data to multiple models

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have created dynamic attributes,
There are three products in the array, then each of them has its own attributes.
Everything works fine initially, once I run "Copy Attributes" code to copy attributes to all other products, the input model starts inserting model value to all other attributes too.

```
for(let i in this.products) {
  if(i != this.product_active) {
    this.products[i].attributes = this.products[this.product_active].attributes
  }
}
```

Here is the fiddle i have created for this issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/sukhcha_in/4o9k2ezn/ 
In this fiddle you will see three products with their own attributes (Input model works fine),
Now press "Copy Attributes" button, attributes of the active product will be copied to other products too.
Now input data to any product, the input model will input same data to all products, instead of selected product. It completely ignores the selected product.
Is there any issue with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copy the same attributes object to all three products, hence the properties are shared.
Instead, you should create a new copy of the object when copying, e. g. like this using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals):

```
for(let i in this.products) {
    if(i != this.product_active) {
        this.products[i].attributes = {... this.products[this.product_active].attributes}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like charm. Didn't knew about spread syntax before :)